# Apache HTTPD Configuration Errors During Restart

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, ssl

When I try to relaunch the Apache HTTP Daemon on OS X 10.10.4 'Yosemite' using either `apachectl graceful` or `apachectl restart` via Terminal, the software spouts the following error messages:

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /Volumes/Development/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf:10
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /Volumes/Development/Sites/ssl/ssl-shared-cert.inc:
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I suppose that resolving the first problem will simply involve removing all mentions of `NameVirtualHost` from HTTPD's configuration files since that directive has been deprecated and no longer does anything, but is this assumption correct?

As for the *other* issue, I have *no* idea *whatsoever* about how to fix it, *especially* since I'm *absolutely sure* I've enabled mod_ssl in my HTTPD configuration files, so how do I work through it?

For reference, [here](https://gist.github.com/RandomDSdevel/b8fd440be0af0ee7799f) is a list of the configuration files which I think may be relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the SSLEngine inside a

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
</VirtualHost>
```

block

Comment: To which of the files I reference should I add these lines?  Or do I already have something like this in one of the configuration files I referenced indirectly?

Comment: this would be the ssl-shared-cert.inc file. Apache also ships with a conf file for this called extra/httpd-ssl.conf.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a whirl!

Comment: Wait a minute:  `ssl-shared-cert.inc` is included into a `VirtualHost` block inside of `httpd-vhosts.conf`!  So why doesn't it already work?

Comment: you're correct, but I don't know if the apache config parser is intelligent enough to see this nesting combined with the include. It might be worth to try to move the included content directly to the file instead of including it.

Comment: OK, I'll try that.

Comment: It didn't work:  I still got the same error messages when I restarted Apache via `apachectl graceful`.  So it appears that Apache _is_ smart enough to properly transclude `ssl-shared-cert.inc` inside of that `VirtualHost` block in `httpd-vhosts.conf`.  Do you have any idea as to what I should try next?

Comment: Can you verify that libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so actually exists? It this is the case what happens when you rename it? Does Apache show an error when you start it with the missing module or does it still return the error you are already getting?

Comment: `/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so` _does_ exist, and Apache throws the error I've been getting anyway.  I'm not sure renaming `mod_ssl.so` would be such a good idea, though…I mean, I don't want to mess Apache up even further!

Comment: Actually you can easily rename it to the original name. This won't harm the install. It might be easier to just run httpd -M though. This should give you a list of static and shared modules used by apache. Are you sure there is only 1 apache install on your system?

Comment: _Dargh_, of _course!_  I installed Apache via Homebrew, so I'm _betting_ that _my_ installation is conflicting with OS X's _default_ one!  I'll get back to you on running `httpd -M`.

Comment: I get the same error messages when I try running `httpd -M`.

Comment: Oh, and, one more thing:  I believe that my attempt to run `httpd` resulted in the loading of _Homebrew's_ copy of HTTPD since I have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` and `/bin` in my `$PATH`.

Comment: Sound like you've answered your own question? Try running the apache binary with the full path and specifying the configuration file. Something like /usr/bin/httpd -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -M With this example I am guessing the installation path of your binary. If this work correctly you can try without specifying the config file. /usr/bin/httpd -M. If this also works you should also be able to run the apachectl command using the full path.

Comment: Sorry I'm taking so long here; I keep forgetting to try what you suggested!

Comment: OK, `/usr/local/bin/httpd -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf -M` gives me the same error message, even after I applied a fix for HTTPD 2.4 that a user suggested in a comment on [the instructions I followed to set my web development environment up](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew#disqus_thread).